# Swift and ZoomSDK, Join a meeting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, zoom-sdk

I have the latest ZoomSDK from their GitHub, but its still really outdated and their documentation doesn't even match their SDK. The example is buggy too and has a whole bunch of extra code that barely works properly.

Has anyone successfully used ZoomSDK to **JOIN a meeting Without Login**?

Here is what I have so far:

```
let zoom: MobileRTC = MobileRTC.shared()
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let context = MobileRTCSDKInitContext.init()
    context.appGroupId = AppConfig.Constants.AppTitle
    context.domain = AppConfig.Constants.WebDomain
    context.enableLog = true

    zoom.initialize(context)

    let auth: MobileRTCAuthService = zoom.getAuthService()!
    auth.clientKey = AppConfig.Constants.AppKey
    auth.clientSecret = AppConfig.Constants.AppSecret
    auth.delegate = self
    auth.sdkAuth()

    return true
}

public func startMeeting(meetingId: String) {

    let user: MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser = MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser.init()
    user.userType = MobileRTCUserType_APIUser
    user.meetingNumber = meetingId
    user.userID = AppConfig.UserHash.UID
    user.isAppShare = false

    guard let meetingService = zoom.getMeetingService() else { return }
    meetingService.customizeMeetingTitle(AppConfig.Constants.AppTitle)
    meetingService.delegate = self

    window = UIApplication.shared.windows.count != 0 ? UIApplication.shared.windows[0] : nil

    // THIS ACTUALLY CRASHES
    meetingService.joinMeeting(with: [
        kMeetingParam_Username: user.userID,
        kMeetingParam_MeetingNumber: user.meetingNumber! as String,
        kMeetingParam_MeetingPassword: ""
    ])

    // Have also tried, does not crash though:
    //let options = MobileRTCMeetingStartParam.init()
    //options.meetingNumber = meetingId
    //options.participantID = AppConfig.UserHash.UID
    //meetingService.startMeeting(with: param)
}
```

All values are OK and I even get back a successful Auth response. It just won't open any Zoom UI or do anything else when trying to start a meeting.

Comment: Same crash here. I just read that they do not support Xcode 11, I don't know if that's your case. I just asked when they plan to support it. https://devforum.zoom.us/t/swift-sdk-crash-on-join-meeting-and-error-150-when-i-try-to-create-a-meeting/6278/7

Comment: I also opened a support ticket, but they closed it without a response. They seem a like a just terrible company all around. But either way, the crash is caused by deprecated UIAlertView code in their library. I know that much at least, so there is nothing WE can do on our end until they get it updated.

Answer (score 1):

> **[SDK](https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-ios/releases)** got updated again and here is the updated version of joining a
> meeting.

```
    let service = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService()
    if service != nil {
        service?.delegate = self
        
        let user = MobileRTCMeetingJoinParam()
        user.meetingNumber = meetingID
        user.userName = userName
        user.zak = "---Your Access Token---"
                    
        let response = service?.joinMeeting(with: user)
        if let response = response {
            print("onJoinMeeting, response: \(response)")
        }
    }
```